# VLC Plugin Memory consumption

Tags: vlc

I have used the vlc plugin(vlc web plugin 2.1.3.0) in Firefox to display the receiving live stream from my server into my browser. and i need to display 16 channels into one web page, but when i play more than 10 channels in the same time, i show that the processor is 100% and some breaking in the video appear. i have checked the plugin-memory in the running task, i have showed that around 45 MB from memory is dedicated for each video (so 10 channels : 10 * 45 = 450 MB).

kindly, do you have any method to reduce the consumption of the VLC plugin to allow the display of 16 channels in the same time ?

best regards,

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that correctly. You could probably save a few megabytes by disabling audio decoding if there are audio tracks in one of your 16 streams in case you don't need them. Except for that, 45MB per stream is quite reasonable in terms of VLC playback and won't be able to go much below that, unless you reduce the video dimensions.

Additionally, your problem is probably not the use of half a giga byte of memory (Chrome and Firefox easily manage to use that much memory by themselves if you open a few tabs), but that VLC exceeds your CPU capacity. Make sure not to use windowless playback since this is less efficient that the normal windowed mode.
VLC 2.2 will improve the performance of the webplugins on windows by adding hardware acceleration known from the standalone application.

Comment: hummmm, thank you my friend feepk, i will try to do this and i hope to be useful. thank you again. regards,